# DataGridView and DataBinding with custom columns

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, datagridview, .net-2.0

My requirement is as follows, I am calling a procedure and I'm populating a `DataTable`. Assume that the procedure is returning `emp_id`, `emp_name`, designation and status. When I use `DataGridView1.DataSource = <Name of the DataTable>`, I get all the columns populated into the DataGridView. How can I display only selected columns in the `DataGridView`. For e.g, I want to show only `emp_id` and `emp_name`.

Similarly, can you please help me as to how I can increase the width of the columns of the DataGridView by writing code.

Comment: Thanks a lot Bobby. It is working fine now. Appreciate your quick response and help. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `AutoGenerateColumns`-Property of the Grid to `False` and add the columns you want by hand. Don't forget that you need to set the `DataPropertyName` of each Grid-Column to the name of the DataTable-Column.

**Edit:** If you want to change the width of the columns, simply set the 'Width' or the 'FillMode'-Property.

Answer (score 0):

The opposite of Bobby's method is to allow the DataGridView autogenerate the columns and then hide your columns by using `dataGrid.Columns("designation").Visible = False.`. One of the advantages of this method is that you don't have to hardcode which columns your hiding.

Answer (score -1):

You can quite easily [select and customize the columns](http://dotnetperls.com/datagridview-columns) on the grid.